# Powershell Workflow Parallel

Tags: powershell

I recently determined that I am able to run a workflow as parallel without using foreach.  Syntax is below.

```
workflow Get-OS {
parallel {
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
    }
}
```

Is it possible to throttle this workflow without using "foreach"?  If so, can I still use the pscomputer parameter when I call it?  I know that this works...

```
workflow Get-OS {
param(
[string[]]$computers
)
foreach -parallel -throttlelimit 50 ($computer in $computers) {
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to do this without creating a "$computers" parameter manually and calling it in the foreach.  Doing it with the PSComputerName parameter would make reporting a LOT easier.

Comment: Why do you want to leave out the `foreach`? What's the motivation here?

Comment: Reporting.  I am trying to gather results of the command.  If I use the PSComputerName parameter, the __SERVER column reports the target server name, if I define the parameter, the __SERVER column reports the name of the server where I ran the script from.

Comment: I edited the original question.  Using the Reboot-Computer cmdlet was a bad example.  It is now more representative of what I would like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No - "Parallel" does not support a throttle limit

---

I think you are confusing two distinct functionalities in PowerShell Workflows:

- `Parallel` (which is a Workflow Foundation keyword)
- `-Parallel` (a Workflow-specific parameter to the `foreach` loop)

The `Parallel` keyword means: "Each of the following statements/sequences can be executed in parallel".

So a `Parallel` block in a workflow, like this:

```
Workflow Test-Parallel {
    Parallel{
        1
        2
        3
        4
    }
}
```

Is not guaranteed to return `@(1,2,3,4)` - it could return the numbers in any order.

To demonstrate this, try the following:

```
function Do-Stuff {
    param($i)

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $(Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 400)
    return $i
}

Workflow Test-Parallel {
    Parallel {
        Do-Stuff -i 1
        Do-Stuff -i 2
        Do-Stuff -i 3
        Do-Stuff -i 4
        Do-Stuff -i 5
        Do-Stuff -i 6
        Do-Stuff -i 7
        Do-Stuff -i 8
        Do-Stuff -i 9
        Do-Stuff -i 10
    }
}

Test-Parallel
```

You should see that the numbers 1 through 10 is returned in a somewhat shuffled order.

---

So, if you know all of the variables (ie. the computer names) beforehand, you could do:

```
Workflow Get-ParallelCS {
    Parallel {
        Get-WmiObject -PSComputerName "client01.domain.tld" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
        Get-WmiObject -PSComputerName "client02.domain.tld" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
        Get-WmiObject -PSComputerName "client03.domain.tld" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
        Get-WmiObject -PSComputerName "client04.domain.tld" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
        Get-WmiObject -PSComputerName "client05.domain.tld" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
        Get-WmiObject -PSComputerName "client06.domain.tld" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
        Get-WmiObject -PSComputerName "client07.domain.tld" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
    }
}

Get-ParallelCS
```